# I want to create a hashtable of ou's in powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

What I want to do is create a table of Ou's and assign a numerical value into memory. If an ou gets deleted I want it to be removed from the hashtable. if a new ou is created I want it to get added to the hashtable. But I want it to fill the missing numerical value for example if i have 1 to 5 but 3 got deleted I want to add the new value to 3 or if they are all there to add a new number like 6

```
function Set-ZLGroupTable{
    $ADOU = (Get-ChildItem "AD:\$OUath").Name
    $GroupTable = @{}
    foreach($GroupName in $ADOU){
    for($count = 0 ; $count -le $ADOU.count; $count++){
        if(!($GroupTable.contains($GroupName))){
            if(!($GroupTable.Keys($count))){
                $GroupTable[$count] = "$GroupName"
                }else{
                    $GroupTable[($ADOU.count++)] = "$GroupName"
                }
           }
     }
    }
    Write-Output $GroupTable

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your original code.

Firstly you need to get a list of OU Names the following way:

```
$ADOU = (Get-ChildItem "AD:\$OUPath")|Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

Your usage of the Hashtable does not seem to be correct. The following line does not determine if the OU name exists as a value in the GroupTable:

```
if(!($GroupTable.contains($GroupName))){
```

In order to determine that you would need to do something along the lines of:

```
if(!($GroupTable.Values -contains $GroupName)){
```

On your original specification you said you wanted the order preserved, but if an OU was removed that the number would still be available for the next available OU name to occupy. The script you have provided above adds an OU into the next available number whether it's occupied or not. What you would need to do is first remove any items that already exist in the hashtable from your source list, then enumerate the remaining items and increment through your count until you have found a place to put it. Also, removal should take place first in order to free up those Keys so we can later insert into them. Something like this:

```
#First we remove items from our list that don't exist in $ADOU
foreach ($key in $GroupTable.Keys){
  if (!($ADOU -contains $GroupTable."$key")){
    $GroupTable.Remove($key)
  }
}
#Next we check if the remaining items already exist in the GroupTable
foreach ($GroupName in $ADOU)
{
  if(($GroupTable.Values -contains $GroupName)){
    #It's already in the GroupTable. Let's not do anything further with it
    $ADOU=$ADOU -ne "$GroupName"
  }
}
#Finally, insert any new OU's into the available GroupTable List:
#Keep increasing the counter until the ADOU array is empty
for ($count = 0; $ADOU.Count -gt 0; $count++)
{
  if ($GroupTable."$count" -eq $null)
  {
    #Add the OU to the table
    $GroupTable."$count" = $ADOU[0]
    #Remove the OU from the list
    $ADOU=$ADOU -ne $ADOU[0]
  }
}
```

The problem with Hashtable output is that the keys rarely print in order. Testing this on my own environment I get 5,0,4,6,1,2,3 as my order.

I hope that helps.

Thanks, Chris.